# what does "great dedication" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> One action that strongly increased our conversion rate was studying the competition with great **dedication**.

I know the meaning of dedication, but here I think it has another meaning. 
dedication means   committed to a task or purpose.

Comment: What is the meaning of "dedication" as far as you know?

Comment: @Stephie I checked in a dictionary. it means committed to a task or purpose

Comment: @user123- exactly.  The task or purpose they were committed to was "studying the competition."

Comment: @user123: Put your comment in your answer (these definitions should *always* be included) and I may finally leave my [soap box](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Great* means "very much" or "intense".

*Dedicate* has multiple meanings.  It can mean

- to memorialize or commemorate someone/something along with the creation of a new building or other artistic work - *We dedicate this work to our late grandfather ... I dedicate this book to my wife ...*
- to exist or focus only towards the furtherance of a specific goal - *This printer is dedicated to invoices, but the other printers can be used to print anything.*
- to concentrate available resources toward a specific goal, with the implication that such resources won't be available for other uses - *Let's dedicate $20,000 to the new project.*

In this case, the third meaning above applies.

Comment: I know the meaning of great I only want the meaning of dedication  in this context.